# SUM Adding Incorrectly When GROUP BY ID is Applied

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help in finding what is wrong in my code regarding a logical error which I'm not able to figure out why is it happening, below is my code:

```
$consultants = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT a.ID, a.USER_ID, a.TASK_ID, SUM(a.MON_BILL+a.TUE_BILL+a.WED_BILL+a.THU_BILL+a.FRI_BILL) AS conhours, a.DELETE_WEEK, b.ID, b.NAME, b.LAST_NAME, c.REF, SUM(c.EXPENSE_COST) AS consultantexpenses, c.DELETE_WEEK FROM b_report_week a INNER JOIN b_user b ON a.USER_ID = b.ID INNER JOIN b_report_expense2 c ON a.ID = c.REF WHERE a.DELETE_WEEK = 0 AND c.DELETE_WEEK = 0 GROUP BY a.USER_ID");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consultants))
{
$conFN = $row['NAME'];
$conLN = $row['LAST_NAME'];
$totalConHours = $row['conhours'];
$totalConExpenses = $row['consultantexpenses'];

print "<tr><td>".$conFN." ".$conLN."</td><td>".$totalConHours."</td><td>".$totalConExpenses."</td>";

}
```

The part that isn't adding up correctly is this part:

```
SUM(a.MON_BILL+a.TUE_BILL+a.WED_BILL+a.THU_BILL+a.FRI_BILL) AS conhours
```

Basically there are five columns each with values in and multiple rows.  The rows also have the USER_ID in them so I want to add all the values in these columns where the USER_ID is the same.  Have have GROUP BY at the end of my statement set to a.USER_ID which is correct.

What is strange is that some figures are correct yet some aren't, well and truly baffled.  I've got the spreadsheet from the database to add up the correct figures and this is how I know some are right and some are wrong.

Any help appreciated.

EXAMPLE:

```
USER_ID   |   MON_BILL  |  TUE BILL  |  WED_BILL  |  THU_BILL  |  FRI_BILL
24        |   8         |  8         |  8         |  8         |  8
24        |   8         |  8         |  8         |  8         |  8
24        |   8         |  8         |  8         |  8         |  8
20        |   8         |  8         |  8         |  8         |  8  
20        |   8         |  8         |  8         |  8         |  8
```

So USER_ID 24 Total Hours should equal: 120 whilst USER_ID 20 = 80.  It's not adding it up like that.

Comment: Please provide example data and example queries for both correct and incorrect results.

Comment: you can not sum like that in mysql sum individually then all get all totals and sum in php or for guide learn `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp`

Comment: Are you sure, there are no NULLs in any of these columns? `NULL +1 = NULL`

Comment: So, what is the SUM?. Then your Join is introducing Duplicates/ ignoring few rows then.

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Comment: SUM is adding up the specified rows and grouping that answer with user id.  You're right that it must be duplicating / ignoring rows but I have no idea how to correct it

Comment: Can you query for `SELECT * FROM b_report_expense2  WHERE REF IN (SELECT ID FROM b_report_week WHERE USER_ID = '24')` It should return three rows, else it is missing something!

Comment: I've taken out the JOIN and the SUM for expense and this has resulted in the figures being correct.  I have introduced a separate query which gives me the desired result for expenses.  Excellent work.

Comment: You were grouping at the `USER_ID` level, but you were selecting details at a lower level and not including them in the `GROUP BY` clause, hence you ended up with multiple lines returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use something like:

```
SUM(a.MON_BILL)+SUM(a.TUE_BILL)+SUM(a.WED_BILL)+SUM(a.THU_BILL)+SUM(a.FRI_BILL) AS conhours
```